# Android Retrofit simple check and print result

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my webservice when i post `userMobileNumber` that checked by server and print result with this format

```
{"result":"1"}
```

when i implementing Retrofit for post and get result i get `No Retrofit annotation found` error

Check Mobile Model:

```
public class CheckMobile {
    private String userMobileNumber;

    public String getUserMobileNumber() {
        return userMobileNumber;
    }

    public void setUserMobileNumber(String userMobileNumber) {
        this.userMobileNumber = userMobileNumber;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public interface TestService {
    @POST("rst_checkmobile")
    Call<CheckMobile> checkMobile(String body);

    public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ClientConfigs.REST_API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

Post and Get result:

```
@OnClick(R.id.request_create_account)
public void RequestCreateAccount(View view) {
    String userMobileNumber = user_mobile_number.getText().toString().trim();
    if (userMobileNumber.length() > 1) {
        TestService testService = TestService.retrofit.create(TestService.class);
        final Call<CheckMobile> call = TestService.checkMobile(userMobileNumber);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CheckMobile>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CheckMobile> call, Response<CheckMobile> response) {
                Log.e("OK: ", response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CheckMobile> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Understand your problem. You should create POJO model class as:

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CheckMobile{

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private String result;


public String getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
this.result = result;
}

}
```

And in your RequestCreateAccount method,

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<CheckMobile>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CheckMobile> call, Response<CheckMobile> response) {
                Log.e("OK: ", response.body().getResult());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CheckMobile> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Try it and let me know if it is working or not. And if not post Error Log.

Answer (score 0):

Call its your respose. 
If you want use it -  just add in CheckMobile.class new field

```
@SerializedName("result")private String result;
```